# Linux + how to know why Linux machine is hung from the messages on the console

Tags: linux, kernel, logs, kernel-panic, core-dump

As the picture below , my VM Linux machine was hung and I cant login

how to identify the reason for the "hung" according to the messages on the console?

I also searched more info from the **/var/log/messages** file ( but I get lost there , I can't find something useful ) , also not exactly know where to find core files?

what the other  files that we can find info for this situation ?

[image: linux machine hung]

[image]

Comment: You've got a hint right there, second line of the screenshot: "task oracle ... blocked for more than ...". Now if you go through the Oracle logs you may be lucky and find more hints about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use boot.log file for information related during boot process information(most linux boot.log will be located in /var/log/boot.log)
2. incase you didn't find the file you can use find command to search the file in following format as  # find / -name "boot.log"
3. dmseg command to see other activities information